# Trying to connect Firebase plus FB Auth and get error

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

Trying to connect FB Auth to Firebase. Appears error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.borisruzanov.social, PID: 20684
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.borisruzanov.social/com.borisruzanov.social.FacebookLoginActivity}: A valid Facebook app id must be set in the AndroidManifest.xml or set by calling FacebookSdk.setApplicationId before initializing the sdk.
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
               Caused by: A valid Facebook app id must be set in the AndroidManifest.xml or set by calling FacebookSdk.setApplicationId before initializing the sdk.
                  at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:276)
                  at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:232)
                  at com.borisruzanov.social.FacebookLoginActivity.onCreate(FacebookLoginActivity.java:49)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618
```

Here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.borisruzanov.social">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".AuthPage">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".GoogleSignInActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".PhoneAuthActivity" >
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".FacebookLoginActivity"
            >
            <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
                android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And also i dont understand why initialization of SDK is not actual and it stroked. I have tried solutions which on stack. Doesn't help.

Also if any1 know the good example where Firebase and Facebook auth integrated well? Because as always firebase guide is totally collapsed my brain.

Comment: Remove `com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId` meta-data tag from activity tag and add it under application tag.

Comment: @Shruti doesn't help

Comment: @Shruti thank you for help! Can you please explain what did we do? Or i need to learn more about gradle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //initialize Facebook SDK
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        FacebookSdk.setIsDebugEnabled(true);
        FacebookSdk.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); }
```

Need add meta-data to Application

```
<application android:label = "@string/app_name" ... > 
    ...
    <meta-data android:name = "com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value = "@string/facebook_app_id" />  
    ...
</ application>
```

instead of

```
<activity android:name=".FacebookLoginActivity"
    >
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
</activity>
```

Comment: does not help at all. That answer was in another topic and i tried it before already

Comment: I know why, in manifest you need to add meta-data to application, current is you added meta-data to <activity android:name=".FacebookLoginActivity".

Comment: I add more in answer, please change in Manifest and test again

Comment: THANK YOU ! You didn't know but it solved not only this problem it solved the main problem which i didn't know how to solve. The problem was that in fb it was logged in but it didn't create a user in firebase. Now everything works. Thx

Comment: @BorisRuzanov great

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to initialize `FacebookSDK` manually as it gets initialized automatically, just change your manifest file as @Boris showed. Hope it will work now.